# Is there a simple method to make a 3D cube from six square matrices?

Tags: graphics, matrix, image, image3d

I'd like to use Graphics3D to display a cube with an image on each face of the cube.  Before I start padding x,y matrices to make x,y,z matrices, I thought I would ask the forum for any other suggestions.

Comment: I'd suggest to create a `Polygon` for each face and use `Texture` and `VertexTextureCoordinates`.

Comment: Yes, I now see the documentation on Polygon -> Neat Example, with Graphics3D.  But I haven't seen a polygon face that is anything but a solid color.

Comment: See `VertexTextureCoordinates`.

Comment: That looks good.

Comment: An image cube is already coded in the mma documentation: Texture>Examples>Applications>Sky Box

Comment: Yes. That's why I suggested to look there (first comment). ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121244/discussion-between-youvan-and-henrik-schumacher).